# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[e -> t]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[e -> t]: NullInjectorError: No provider for tI

Tags: cordova, build, ionic4

Ionic page is not opening when I build the production app with following command:
 - ionic cordova build android --prod --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path --buildOptimizer

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[e -> t]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[e -> t]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
Error: StaticInjectorError[e -> t]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[e -> t]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
at t.get (main.0ba0a52252d542706570.js:1)
at main.0ba0a52252d542706570.js:1
at t (main.0ba0a52252d542706570.js:1)
at t.get (main.0ba0a52252d542706570.js:1)
at main.0ba0a52252d542706570.js:1
at t (main.0ba0a52252d542706570.js:1)
at t.get (main.0ba0a52252d542706570.js:1)
at Ru (main.0ba0a52252d542706570.js:1)
at t.get (main.0ba0a52252d542706570.js:1)
at Ru (main.0ba0a52252d542706570.js:1)
at P (polyfills.102b4f7c459a8c593a9f.js:1)
at P (polyfills.102b4f7c459a8c593a9f.js:1)
at polyfills.102b4f7c459a8c593a9f.js:1
at e.invokeTask (polyfills.102b4f7c459a8c593a9f.js:1)
at Object.onInvokeTask (main.0ba0a52252d542706570.js:1)
at e.invokeTask (polyfills.102b4f7c459a8c593a9f.js:1)
at t.runTask (polyfills.102b4f7c459a8c593a9f.js:1)
at g (polyfills.102b4f7c459a8c593a9f.js:1)
```

Without production flag, build has no issue. All pages are opened, but their load time is significantly high. Any help will be a great favor.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to Screen Orientation plugin.
I simply uninstalled it from using npm and cordova.

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
npm uninstall @ionic-native/screen-orientation
```

And removed it from pages where it was used.